# Accessing the object of an observable in the component (not the HTML Template)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am building a MATERIAL autocomplete for an angular project.
Modeling after this Stackblitx...
https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.ts

The example creates an array of 5 states.
I would like to  pull an array of accounts from a service.

The example is clear in its intent.
There is an observable on the text control value.
When the text control value changes, the observable calls a method to filter the larger array of states into an array where the name contains what has been typed so far into the text box.

I am stumbling on the difference in that I do not have a complete array of accounts.
I have an observable of a complete array of accounts.

```
 private _filterStates(value: string): State[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    ///**** This works b/c states is an array  of states 
    return this.states.filter(state => state.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }

  private _filterAccount(value: string): COA_Account[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
     //this is not working because the Observable of Accounts[] does not have a .filter method.
   //  it isnt an array! its an observable. 
    return this.Accounts$.filter(acct => acct.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
                           
                      );
  }
```

My question is, how do I access the content of the observable in the class.
I know how to do it in the html.
I feel like I am missing something basic here.

My approach so far is to also define an array and populate that when the observable completes

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.Accounts$ = this.myAcctSvc.getCOAByProjectId(4200).pipe(
         switchMap((data : COA_Header) =>{
         
          //this works, but Im not sure its the correct way
          this.myAccounts  = data.Accounts;

          return of(this.myAccounts);
        }));
  }
```

**MY QUESTION IS** Is there a way to access the Account[] array via the Accounts$ observable.

Comment: You want something like `return this.Accounts$.pipe(map(accts) => accts.filter(acct => acct.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)));`, and then change `_filterAccount` to return  `Observable<COA_Account[]>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing your approach to staying in the observable stream as much as possible. It looks like you probably are already subscribing to `Accounts$` in the template. That is great. What you can do is use RXJS to manipulate the stream in a way that will react to the input of the user.

I would suggest using a [reactive form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) for your input, and combine the input stream with the accounts stream like so:

```
form = this.fb.group({ query: [''] });

// Every new query will retrigger this stream
accounts$ = combineLatest([
  this.myAcctSvc.getCOAByProjectId(4200),
  this.form.controls.query.valueChanges.pipe(
    // Start with initial value ('') as valueChanges doesn't emit anything to start
    startWith(this.form.controls.query.value)
  ),
]).pipe(
  map(([accounts, query]) =>
    // If there is a query, do the filter, else return all accounts query
      ? accounts.filter((acct) =>
          acct.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(query)
        )
      : accounts
  )
);
```

[See this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hgh2ru?file=src/main.ts)

Comment: thank you, i have been pulled off. i will try to implement later this week. i very much appreciate teh time.